# How do I deserialize a json list string to a list of object strings?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, json.net

I have a string object which I am trying to deserilize but when there is a json object in an another json object it has issues deserilizing.

```
[
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "Account",
      "url": "/services/data/77.0/object/Account/1234"
    },
    "Id": "1234",
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "MasterRecordId": null,
    "Name": "Stevens Smith",
    "LastName": null,
    "FirstName": null,
    "Salutation": null,
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "Account",
      "url": "/services/data/v77.0/object/Account/12345"
    },
    "Id": "12345",
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "MasterRecordId": null,
    "Name": "Mr John Smith",
    "LastName": null,
    "FirstName": null,
    "Salutation": null,
  }
]
```

My Class is defined as follows:

```
    public Account() {
    public string? attributes;
    public string? id;
    public string? isDeleted;
    public string? masterRecordId;
    public string? name;
    public string? lastName;
    public string? firstName;
    public string? salutation;
}
```

The error message I get is Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '[0].attributes', line 3, position 19.

Comment: Oh salesforce...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have two classes

```
public class Account() {
    public Attrubute attributes;
    public string? id;
    public string? isDeleted;
    public string? masterRecordId;
    public string? name;
    public string? lastName;
    public string? firstName;
    public string? salutation;
}

public class Attrubute() {
    public string? type;
    public string? url;
}
```

If you just want to save the `Attrubute` object as a string you could do something like this (syntax could be different depending if you're using newtonsoft or not)

```
public class Account() {
    public Attrubute attributes;
    public string? id;
    public string? isDeleted;
    public string? masterRecordId;
    public string? name;
    public string? lastName;
    public string? firstName;
    public string? salutation;
    public string attributesString => attributes != null ? JsonConvert.Serialize(attributes) : string.empty;
}
```

You want don't want to define the `Attrubute` class. You could make it dynamic object and if you want the string version - you could convert within your class. So something like this

```
public class Account {
    public string? id;
    public string? isDeleted;
    public string? masterRecordId;
    public string? name;
    public string? lastName;
    public string? firstName;
    public string? salutation;
    
    public dynamic attributes;
    public string Attributes => attributes != null ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attributes) : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I see, is there a way to store the json object as a string?

Comment: @apolloSN - I made a change in the answer of how you could potentially go about it if you want attributes to stay a string.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do this without defining the object and just put it into the original string?

Comment: @apolloSN - I made another edit of what you could do if you don't want to define the `Attribute` model.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your variables are the wrong type. It's much safer to use the correct types - that way if you ever reserialize to JSON it will stay valid (for example isDeleted - even if you parse it in as a string, reserializing would store it as :"false" instead of :false).

```
public class Account
{
    public Attrubute attributes;
    public string stringAttributes //if you need a string accessor to attributes you can just use a property
        {
            get {
                return $"{attributes?.type}:{attributes?.url}";
            }
        }
    public string? id;
    public bool isDeleted;
    public string? masterRecordId;
    public string? name;
    public string? lastName;
    public string? firstName;
    public string? salutation;
}

public class Attrubute
{
    public string? type;
    public string? url;
}
```

If you do want to keep things as string, a better option is to leave it as json instead with JObject, and call .ToString() to return the json value when needed

```
public class Account
{
    public JObject attributes;
    public string? id;
    public JObject isDeleted;
    public string? masterRecordId;
    public string? name;
    public string? lastName;
    public string? firstName;
    public string? salutation;
    public string GetAttributesJson() {
         return attributes.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need attributes as string you can do it using a counstructor for example, but before you will have to fix the class by adding getter/setter

```
List<Account> accounts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Account>>(json);

public class Account
{
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public string? attributes { get; set; }
    //.... another properties
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Account(JObject attributes)
    {
        this.attributes = string.Join(",", attributes.Properties());

       //or a json string
       this.attributes =  attributes.ToString();

      // or a url
       this.attributes = (string)attributes["url"]

    }
}
```